# RecyclerView en Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, fragment

aquí con otra pregunta estoy haciendo una aplicación en Android y el problema es que al llamar el RecyclerView me arroja este error:

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Pero no se porque me de este error y solo recorre una vez el arreglo, aquí les deje mi codigo

```
 public class InicioFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "Inicio";
protected String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.3/proyecto/";
private RecyclerView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
    LinearLayoutManager linear = new LinearLayoutManager(inflater.getContext());
    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    listView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.tatuajeslist);
    listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    listView.setLayoutManager(linear);
```

Por lo que he investigado dicen que es:

> linear.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

Pero la mera verdad no se que sea, otros dicen que es el contexto, ¿no se si tenga que ver que este usando Retrofit?

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar porfavor?, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

te arroja ese error porque no estas añadiendo ningun adapter con los datos a mostrar y por tanto no tiene nada que cargar y visualizar.

Tienes que añadir una linea de este tipo:

```
listView.setAdapter(tu_adapter);
```

Y previamente a eso deberias haber creado tu adapter con los datos a mostrar.

Te dejo una pagina donde lo explican mas detalladamente:

[Using lists in Android wth ListView - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Saludos.

Comment: Te refieres a esto: final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new ListAdapter(response.body().getAlgo());
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Exactamente. Tienes que tener y rellenar tu adapter y luego pasarselo al listview para que este lo muestre.

Comment: pero si lo tengo eso lo hago despues de obtener el json y parsearlo, funciona pero me sigue dando ese error y no se porque

Comment: Porque no se está parseando bien. Si el adapter falla al parsear los datos no se añade al listview. En tu codigo no veo que eso este añadido y no veo como parseas los datos asi que poco mas puedo decirte salvo que vayas paso a paso debugeando donde se parsea el json y veas que objeto le pasas al adapter y si luego este es capaz de operar con el.